# ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Как стал использовать аудио и видео файлы в своем приложении на Django получаю данную ошибку, которая замедляет работу локального сервера. Ошибка появляется после загрузки страницы и дублируется столько раз, сколько медиа файлов на странице в данный момент. Я установил CORS и открыл доступ к локальному хосту, так же сделал установку `pip install vprof`, проблема сохраняется, пробовал отключать антивирус, не помогает. Операционная система у меня Windows.
Для примера метод выгрузки данных на страницу:

```
class ObjectPersonalAccountMixin:
    modelUser = None
    modelAudio = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request, pk):
        ctx = {}
        obj_user = self.modelUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
        audios = self.modelAudio.objects.filter(user=obj_user)
        ctx['audios'] = audios
        return render(request, self.template, ctx)
```

Модель аудио файла:

```
class Audio(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    author_track = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    title_track = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    audio = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path_audio, content_types=['audio/mpeg'], max_upload_size=52428800,
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    reposts = GenericRelation(Repost, related_query_name='Audio')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.audio.close()
        self.audio.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Метод хранения аудио файлов:

```
def user_directory_path_audio(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.user, 'audio', filename)
```

И Traceback:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54424)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение
----------------------------------------
```